# Prevent user to read files from vfat filesystems - but allow to write

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, file-permissions, vfat

Its possible do that? I want to mount a flash drive(vfat) in linux and the user be able to write to it but not to read.

I've tried:

> mount /dev/sdb1 /media/mpoint  -o fmask=0444

but no results. After that I'm still able to read the files in the flash drive.

Comment: What operating system exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot specify about that, is linux.

Comment: Why the down vote? I need some explanation if some of you think I'm doing something wrong or my question is bad.

Comment: I voted up - thinking about it, the question is actually pretty interesting.

Comment: I thought about a more complicated approach to solve it, and wrote another independent answer (deleted the old) - but I think it's much more effort than you planned for. But if you're interested, I could try to find a suitable file system.

Answer (score 1):

To solve that, you obviously need a **better permission system** than a FAT file system provides. That can be solved by using an **overlay filesystem**:

The **FAT filesystem** is mounted normally, and **not accessible at all** for the user.
The **permissions** are handled by a file system that stores it's files just as files on the FAT filesystem - but can implement additional features, like a permission system.
(I do not know which filesystem would match your needs - but I assume there is more than one that could be used, ignoring most of their features.)

That overlay- or union filesystem is what the user will access, and where you can set restricted permissions.
The **permission** system would be just the **normal Unix**/Linux style.
Using that, you can just set **write-only permissions** on all files and directories.
To navigate a directory, the user does not need to list the file- and directory names in it;  But he needs to access the involved directories themselves - `.` and `..`.

You can allow just what he needs with a special kind of permission: **Directories** have the **x permission like files** - but are **not executable** in the first place. This unused directory execute permission is used to handle **just what you need**. If the r bit is not set, but the x is, the user can still read just the little bit he needs here.

Then, the user **can not list them**, but he can make use of directories he knows himself. He **can **cd** into** known directories.

To set the right permissions for new files, set a **restrictive umask** for the user.

Comment: This looks very interesnting, suppose I want to use "ext3" as filesystem, can you post an example? Is this supported in the kernel or is just for one distribution (Ubuntu, for instance).